# SQL Cube Calculation not working as intended in a CASE statement?

Tags: sql, ssas, mdx, business-intelligence

I have a SQL SSAS cube deployed, I am using basic Calculated Members and seem to be having issues with the following..

When I have a calculated member as such:

```
Case
When ([Measures].[QTY SHIPPED] + [Measures].[QTY ADJUST]) is null OR ([Measures].[QTY SHIPPED] + [Measures].[QTY ADJUST]) = 0 
THEN 0
ELSE [Measures].[NET SALES CAD] / ([Measures].[QTY SHIPPED] + [Measures].[QTY ADJUST]) 
END
```

I get !#Value for my result cells in Excel..

However, when the calculated member is..

```
[Measures].[NET SALES USD] / ([Measures].[QTY SHIPPED] + [Measures].[QTY ADJUST])
```

Removing the CASE statement, it works as expected.. the issue here is, if I don't wrap it in a CASE I get #NUM! values for columns that are divide by zero.

Any idea why the CASE statement does not work in this calculated member?

Answer (score 0):

I have not reviewed why your CASE statement is not working but I use IIF for similar results for creating calculated member which should work for you too :

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[FOO]
AS IIF(([Measures].[QTY SHIPPED] + [Measures].[QTY ADJUST])=0 OR ([Measures].[QTY SHIPPED] + [Measures].[QTY ADJUST]) = NULL,
NULL,
[Measures].[NET SALES CAD] / ([Measures].[QTY SHIPPED] + [Measures].[QTY ADJUST]) 
);
```